# Select max for a tuple in table

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like this:

```
host, job, folder, file, mtime
```

Folder names are not unique and can be same for a job spread across different hosts. I need to pick folder where the max(mtime for a file) is the max across all the folders by the same name across different hosts. Roughly I need something like this:

```
Select (host, folder) pair where tuple (host, job, folder) max(max (file mtime))
```

Example:

```
1, j1, f1, e1, 2
2, j1, f1, e2, 0
2, j1, f1, e9, 3
3, j1, f1, e3, 2
1, j2, f2, e4, 3
2, j2, f2, e5, 4
3, j2, f2, e6, 5
1, j3, f3, e7, 6
2, j3, f3, e8, 7
```

result would be:

```
2, j1, f1, e9, 3
3, j2, f2, e6, 5
2, j3, f3, e8, 7
```

The table is huge, so I trying to find out best possible way to do this. Thanks

Comment: MySQL or SQLite ? Please tag only the one database you are using.

Comment: It's Sqlite actually. Apologies for multiple tags. @GMB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A window function like `ROW_NUMBER()` should provide the best performance:

```
SELECT host, job, folder, file, mtime
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY folder, job ORDER BY mtime DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
) 
WHERE rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wU2LNnbAWoC66xJcxW5HbF/0).
Results:

```
| host | job | folder | file | mtime |
| ---- | --- | ------ | ---- | ----- |
| 2    | j1  | f1     | e9   | 3     |
| 3    | j2  | f2     | e6   | 5     |
| 2    | j3  | f3     | e8   | 7     |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.mtime = (
    select max(t1.mtime) from mytable t1 where t1.folder = t.folder and t1.job = t.job
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `(folder, job, mtime)`.

You did not specify how you want to handle potential top ties (rows that relate to the same `folder` and `job` with the maximum `mtime`): this query does return them.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question. I first need to pick max mtime of files in any given folder. Now for same (job, folder) pair, I need to find row corresponding to max of max mtimes (found previously.

Comment: @Maxsteel: OK. I changeed the query accordingly (that's still the same logic, but with two columns in the correlation clause).